# Pointer becomes null when passed by stack

Tags: c, opencv, c-api

I have very strange (rather impossible) issue with one of **OpenCV**'s functions - pointer passed to `cvGetSize`, inside `cvGetSize` becomes `NULL`. I get checked them  inside `CvGetSize`, it's really becomes `NULL`. There is no dereferences, just cast.

How can this be possible? (lang: C, compiler MSVC 2012)

My code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core_c.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>

void Test(IplImage * img)
{
    CvArr * arr = (CvArr*)(img);
    printf("img in test = %p\n", (CvArr*)img);
    cvGetSize(arr);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    IplImage * img;
    img = cvLoadImage("D:\\fusion.jpeg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Test(img);
    return 0;
}
```

Signature of `cvGetSize`:

```
CV_IMPL CvSize cvGetSize( const CvArr* arr )
```

Also i add output of pointer to `cvGetSize`.

Output:

```
img in test = 000000B2F5536F80
img in cvGetSize = 000007F9058A8670
```

Update:
If i make this sample to be CPP file, all works fine.

Comment: Show a small snippet how this function is called, edit your question please!

Comment: Try `cvGetSize(static_cast<CvArr*>(img));`. `CvArr*` is a typedef for `void*`.

Comment: It's a "C", there is no static_cast. I use "C" cast - (CvArr*) but it is the same.

Comment: the c-api is dead. avoid it.

Comment: It's just pointers! No math, no something other, just cast to void*.

Comment: Update your question to show a [complete self-contained program](http://sscce.org/); what you posted is missing the `#include` directives, among other things. Add something like this: `printf("img = %p\n", (void*)img);` to your `f1` function and show us the output.

Comment: Thanks for silently updating the question so that my answer no longer makes any sense!

Comment: You can see that is no any valuable difference with code posted at start and this code. It's totaly same. But error with pointer still here.

Comment: please , people, can we stop this insane discussion ? the question should be reworded to: "stubborn user insists on using a deprecated api and promply shoots herself into the foot". all your well-meant efforts encourage the wrong thing ! opencv moved to a (very different) c++ api 5 years ago. the whole problem above is just ...

Comment: So i found very original solution - change filename extension to cpp and problem gone. I really can't understand what can occure with pointer that it becomes null while it just passed to function.

Answer (score -1):

Actually the passed pointer is not treated as a const, compare:

```
const CvArr * arr ;
```

which stands for a pointer to a const

```
CvArr * const arr ;
```

which stands for a const pointer

You can check it like this:

```
int x = 1 ;
int y = 2 ;
const int *p = &x ;
cout << *p ; // 1
p = &y ;
cout << *p << x << y ; // 212
const int * const pc = &x ;
pc = &y ; // Compilation Error
```

So it looks like a valid behaviour

Comment: Const does not make sense here.

Comment: What do you mean? I meant that from colpiler's view pointer nullification is correct, since function doesn't guarantee pointer constness

Comment: _arr in f1 is a pointer to const object. cvGetSize receive the same type - pointer to const object, so cvGetSize guarantees that _arr contents will not be changed.  Why pointer should become a null?

Comment: in this case pointer contents ( i.e. *ptr ) don't change, the pointer itself changes.

Comment: Pointer itself (address) not changed inside cvGetSize (or somewhere in  callstack). I haven't ever seen auto nullification of pointers due cv-qualifiers .

Comment: Then I didn't get you: "Pointer itself (address) not changed inside cvGetSize" vs "pointer passed to cvGetSize, inside cvGetSize becomes NULL"

Comment: The const has nothing to do with this. Furthermore, your answer is in the wrong programming language.

Comment: Lundin, could you eplain please?

Comment: Lundin, it was tagged [c++] when I answered so it was ok

Comment: Your comments have no relation whatsoever to the question. He is asking why a parameter turns NULL. You answer something unrelated about compiler errors during casts of const variables. Compiler errors do not turn variables into NULL in runtime...